# doing anything with value with this thing doesnt work

Tags: roblox

```
if  script.Parent.Value.Value == 5  then
    print("Health is 5")
end
```

that above, is actually int value like  a health of a wall. when i set this value manually this does work. but i have like a monster type of thing which damages the wall when it damages it to that  much health it doesnt work. here's the script of damaging it:

```
local ms = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("ls") -- ls is monster

script.Parent.Parent.Torso.Touched:Connect(function(Hit) -- dont mind why wall is called 
 torso
    
    if Hit:IsDescendantOf(ms) and script.Parent.Parent.Value.Value >= 10  then
        script.Parent.Parent.Value.Value = script.Parent.Parent.Value.Value - 5 
        
    end
    
end)
```

please keep in mind im bad at roblox scripting. and please answer why that doesnt work(why it doesnt print that out when value is 5).